# Obtener número de cadena

Tags: sql

Saludos.
Actualmente estoy teniendo un problema con la base de datos, ya que los usuarios ingresan mal la información (los usuarios son imposibles de corregir).
Tengo una base de datos en la cual hay un campo en el cual se ingresa la cantidad. Pero los usuarios al ingresar ponen .500 Ton, 5 Ton, 500 lbs, o cosas por el estilo

Actualmente uso esta función para obtener el número, pero aún tengo ciertos detalles. Algo más general para extraer números me serviría.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumbers](@Data VarChar(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR (8000)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @intAlpha INT
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9.,]%', @Data)
        BEGIN
            WHILE @intAlpha > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Data = STUFF(@Data, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
                SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9.,]%', @Data )
            END
        END
        BEGIN
            IF RIGHT(RTRIM(@Data),1) = '.'
            BEGIN
                SET @Data = LEFT(@Data, LEN(@Data) - 1)
            END
        END
    RETURN ISNULL(@Data, 0)     
    END
GO
```

Intenté otra opción, que era borrar todo antes del espacio en blanco, pero por alguna razón no me borra en todos los campos (no tengo idea como lo escriben los usuarios, pero no borra esos espacios en blanco escritos, en Word se ve como el símbolo de grados cuando se muestran caracteres ocultos)

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Primero, Disculpen, no se mucho español. " (los usuarios son imposibles de corregir)" Me parece que el programador no debe permitir información mala de primero.

Comment: Por que no escribe una metoda a limpiar la informacion mala? Despues no permite que los usuarios den mas mala informacion.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a SOes, sería conveniente que indiques como accedes a la base de datos,  y que deseas hacer, ya que existen muchas formas de resolver el problema que tenés. Saludos

Comment: La base de datos ya está establecida, no puedo cambiar la estructura sin dañar mucha de la información que ya está ahí. Estoy haciendo un reporte de algunas tablas y esa tiene la información mala. Lo que quiero hacer es simplemente obtener el valor númerico de una columna. Si escriben .500 Ton, quiero obtener .500, si ponen 1.5 Ton quiero obtener 1.5

Comment: Como indica @ B. Clay Shannon, sería bueno validar y limpiar los datos antes de  que estos ingresen a la consulta. Si pudieras mostrar algo de código de esa parte sería ideal para ayudarte. ¿Qué lenguaje de programación estas usando?

Comment: Lo sé, pero no puedo modificar el código fuente. Cuando llegue a la empresa el programa ya estaba hecho y ya tienen algunos cientos de miles de registros ingresados de esa manera. Lo que ando haciendo es en SQL

Answer (score 1):

Primero, jamas permitas al usuario introducir datos del tipo que no toca, filtra la entrada para que solo permita números.
Si los datos ya han sido introducidos, usa expresiones regulares.

En tu caso, para obtener un numero con decimales usa la expresion: \d*?.\d*

Si además te encuentras que como separador decimal usan "," usa esta otra: \d*?(.|,)\d*

Mas informacion:

[Introducción al uso de las Expresiones Regulares en una Base de Datos Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/sql/expresiones-regulares-base-de-datos-1569340-esa.html)

[Expresiones regulares en MySQL](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?cap=regulares%20%22%22)

Comment: No puedo hacer mucho, cuando llegué aquí el programa ya estaba hecho. No puedo modificar el código fuente. Lo que puedo hacer es algunas stored procedures y funciones en la base de datos para hacer lo mejor posible al sacar los datos :(

Comment: En ese caso haz una procedure para sacar los números, que filtre los datos con la expresión regular que indico, y si después lo convierte a double, mejor. Y usa esa procedure en lugar de la actual.